# How create a upload-form?

Tags: file-upload

i need to set on my web page a upload form for videos and i want that this videos are sent to my mail.

i found this code

```
<form name="myWebForm" action="mailto:annie.etoile@gmail.com" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10mb" />
<input type="video" name="uploadField" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

But when i press on "Send" it opens my mailing software, it doesn't send autmatically to me the video.

Maybe there's something wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It "opens your mail software" because that's exactly what it's being told to do here:

```
action="mailto:annie.etoile@gmail.com"
```

When you say you want it to "upload"... Where do you want it to go?  If you want to send it to the web server then you need some server-side resource which can receive it.  For example, if you have a PHP page which accepts the file upload, you'd change your form action to that page:

```
action="fileupload.php"
```

Then you'd have server-side code in that PHP file to accept the uploaded file and do whatever you want to do with it.  (Including [mail it to you](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).)

It doesn't have to be PHP on the server-side code, any server-side language/framework/environment/etc. can do the job.  The point is that you'd need *something* there.  If all you have is client-side code (which is all you have in the question) then the `mailto:` action is about as good as it's going to get.

Comment: Yes, 
I'm absolutly don't able to use php :-/

And i want to send the video on my mail. I don't have a php server!

Comment: @Annah: This sounds like a good opportunity to learn some web development, then.  Where are you hosting this page?  What options are available for server-side functionality on that host?  If it's a server you control then you can install PHP on it, or ASP.NET, or Ruby, or anything you like.  The next step would be some introductory tutorials for developing a website in your chosen platform.  (Google will help find a lot of those.)  If all you have is HTML then I don't think you can attach a file via that.  (Though your mail software can, which you'd be using anyway.)

Comment: Thank you Daivde for your kind answer. So, my page is on one.com and now i've seen that i have php. but i don't know how to install php and unfortly i have enough time to learn :-///